# C++/SDL need help getting an image on screen

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I cant seem to load a image onto a SDL window.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

SDL_Window *window;
SDL_Surface *imageSurface;
SDL_Surface *image;

void createWindow() {

    SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING;

    if(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING <0) {
       cout << "SDL failed to initialize!" << endl;
    }

    window = SDL_CreateWindow("Test Window", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 640, 480,0);

    if (window==NULL) {
        cout << "Window could not be made" << endl;
    }

    imageSurface = SDL_GetWindowSurface(window);
}

void close() {
    SDL_FreeSurface(image);
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

void loadmedia() {

    image = SDL_LoadBMP("Test.bmp");

    if (image==NULL) {
        cout << "Image could not be loaded" << endl;
    }
}

int main() {

    createWindow();
    loadmedia();

    SDL_BlitSurface(image, NULL, imageSurface, NULL);
    SDL_UpdateWindowSurface(window);
    SDL_Delay(10000);

    close();
}
```

Comment: Sooo, what exactly is happening? "nothing seems to work" is not really a helpful description of your problem

Comment: @unholysheep the window appears but stays blank

Comment: Please post the relevant code here as well.

Comment: It is unreasonable to expect us to go through all your code. It is even more unreasonable to ask that without being specific about what you want it to do, and what it's doing or failing to do instead. Post the essential parts of the code here (as an edit, and keep the link for reference), and provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: okay fixed it, for some reason xcode was not recognising file names so i switched to absoulate paths in the image loading functions and everything worked, if your a beginner at SDL i suggest you do not follow lazy foos tutorials until you are more experienced as they are targeted towards experienced sdl developers

Answer (score -1):

You are missing the message loop.
Basically, your application is receiving messages to process operations such as drawing the window and all.

What you are missing is something like that:

```
while (!done) {
  while (SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
    if (event.type == SDL_QUIT)
      done = true;
  }
}
```

You can find a sample here: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/376858-a-proper-sdl-message-loop/